# Are there "natural" non-noetherian schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

In algebraic geometry's books, there are many propositions like "let $f : X \to Y$ be a morphism of locally finite presentation, then such-and-such...", but every time I face on such propositions, the question comes up to my mind.

I'm a beginner in studying algebraic geometry, but I feel that almost all schemes in practice are noetherian, like that almost all rings are noetherian.
And these propositions becomes so clear if schemes are noetherian.
So I want to restrict the situations to  noetherian schemes, if it will not have any problems.

So the question is: are there non-noetherian schemes in practice?

p.s.
I want to study arithmetic geometry, so if there is, please give me any examples of this field.

Comment: In his (free!) book Foundations of Algebraic Geometry, Ravi Vakil argues that “most rings you care about are noetherian” (I think the section is literally called “Why you should not worry about noetherian hypotheses”). On the other hand, adeles, certain rings in Class Field Theory (and arithmetic Geometry) are not noetherian.

Comment: In positive characteristics, one often encounters rings that are not perfect, i.e. the Frobenius $R \xrightarrow{r \mapsto r^p} R$ is not an isomorphism. To fix this, one can pass to the perfection $R^{1/p^\infty}$ which can be defined as the direct limit of the iterated Frobenius map. This is almost never noetherian if $R$ is not a field, for instance it is not if $R=k[x]$.

Once you leave classical geometry, i.e. once you care for more than only schemes of finite type over a field, non-noetherian situations occur from time to time.

Comment: There natural non-noetherian scheme (but locally noetherian) which are very commonly used. For example, if you see $\mathbb{Z}$ as a scheme it won't be noetherian (since it has infinite many irreducible components). And this scheme is used very often...

Comment: 1) An affine scheme $Spec(R)$ is noetherian (as scheme, not as topological space!) iff $R$ is a noetherian ring. So $Spec(\Bbb Z)$ is a noetherian scheme.  2) You might have non-noetherian schemes occuring in moduli theory. In general, the Picard scheme $Pic_{X/S}$ is only _locally_ of finite type over $S$ (hence _locally_ noetherian if $S$ is).

Comment: @Roland What is Z as a scheme? Is it the disjoint union of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{F}_p$ and $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Q}$ ?
And would you tell me some applications of this?

Comment: @agababibu It depends on the base scheme, say you work over a fixed field $k$. Then $\mathbb{Z}=\coprod_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\operatorname{Spec}k$. It is useful for example because it is a group scheme which represents... well $\mathbb{Z}$. In other words, its $k$-points (even its $\overline{k}$-points) form the group $\mathbb{Z}$.